# Web development production / test / dev environment setup

Tags: language-agnostic

I am building ASP.NET sites. I was wondering what's the industrial standard to set up prod/test/dev environment. There are 2 approaches I know:

1. create 3 domains:

   www.mysite.com
   test.mysite.com
   dev.mysite.com

Further question here: is it good to put them all on same machine? or put production one on one machine, and test/dev both on the other machine in private network.

2. use hosts file to point to different machines

```
1.2.3.4      www.mysite.com  # production server
192.168.0.1  www.mysite.com  # dev server
192.168.0.2  www.mysite.com  # test server
```

or if I want to consolidate test/dev sites.

```
1.2.3.4      www.mysite.com  # production server
192.168.0.1  dev.mysite.com  # dev server
192.168.0.1  test.mysite.com  # test server
```

Can the community advise a more systematic/organize/scalable approach? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a "production" machine and a "staging" machine.  Our "development" machine is the local developer's PC.  You should NOT put production on the same box as testing and development.

Comment: what about URL, do you use same one? And for the staging server, do you push the site to live from staging server by any deployment tool automatically? Please advise.

Comment: No, we use a different subdomain for the different sites, similar to what you've shown.